# What does "Trump’s live tweeting of Fox and Friends" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain it for me, please? What was it?

"It’s easy to say that Merkel is the new leader of the free world, and, perhaps on social issues, she is. But her decade-plus of economic governance is as reckless as **Trump’s live tweeting of “Fox and Friends.”**"

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/the-world-leader-posing-the-biggest-threat-to-global-economy-isnt-trump-2017-05-15

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What don't you understand? The phrase **live tweeting**?  The reference to "Fox and Friends"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s another [article](http://theweek.com/speedreads/684372/president-trump-spent-morning-livetweeting-fox--friends) about this event.

Mr. Trump watched a television show called “[Fox and Friends](http://www.foxnews.com/on-air/fox-and-friends/).”

Then he expressed some opinions about the show by sending electronic messages to Twitter. Sending this sort of message is called “[tweeting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tweet).”